# Get which process/window is actually visible in C#

Tags: c#, process, window, visible

I have a list of all open windows, the ones in the windows taskbar. What I want to do is to remove the ones that are not visible from the list.

What I mean is, if a window is hidden by another one, it should not be in my list.

I've been searching google for the past two days without success...

Any ideas?

PS: I can get the location and size of each process, so getting the last time a process was used/idle time would work too...

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by the location and size of a process. It's windows that have size and location, not processes. Idle time won't help either. An obscured window can be busy or idle, likewise a top most window.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use regions, what's still visible of the window can be a complex set of rectangles.  Start with the window you want to check, GetWindowRect and CreateRectRegion to create a region for the window rectangle.

Call GetWindow() in a loop, passing GW_HWNDPREV.  Which returns the previous window in the Z-order so it could overlap.  GetWindowRect() to get its rectangle, CreateRectRegion() and combine that with the original window region using CombineRgn() with RGN_DIFF.

When GetWindow returns NULL you've found all possible overlapping windows.  Use GetRgnBox to check if there's anything left of the region.  If there is, at least one part of the window wasn't overlapped.

Comment: Cr*p, it's C#.  You'll need to pinvoke GetWindowRect and GetWindow, use pinvoke.net.  You can use the .NET Region class for the rest.

Comment: @David - OT: how do you see other people posting to a question so quickly?

Comment: @Hans F5! I'm always interested in your answers anyway. Of course, it's an exercise for the reader to deal with non-rectangular windows!

Comment: @Hans Two or three. I guess I was just lucky this time, or have you detected a pattern?

Comment: Hoping for magic, I miss too many posts and the star doesn't float my boat.

Comment: @Hans: The new guy, Erik, he mentioned something he uses called [StackGuru](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65170/stackguru-chrome-extension) but I'm too much of a Luddite to be able to work out what it does or how it helps. Now that guy is fast.

Comment: He is, looks like Skeet is using it too.  Thanks @David.