# Is there a way to determine if a windows window is really visible

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I'm using windows api EnumChildWindows to get all parent and child windows and IsWindowVisible to determine if WS_VISIBLE is set. But WS_VISIBLE can also be set for windows totally obscured by others.

Is there a way to determine if a window is really visible without cycling z-order?

Comment: Yes, the window could also be minimized. This is a tricky problem to solve. See Hans's answer here: [Get which process/window is actually visible in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445889/get-which-process-window-is-actually-visible-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you for the link, after some research it looks like that's the best way to do.
I tried to hit test by using WindowFromPoint function, but it has quite an impact on performance checking many points, so i decided to build my z-order as described by Hans

Comment: Note, however, that it is almost always bad UI design for software to behave differently based on whether a window is visible.

Comment: Goal is to visualize currently opened and visible windows along with z-order inside our application, which itself doesn't behave differently.