# I am trying to check if the window is how much obscured by other windows. But the code always return the same value

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using this code its simple code but for some reason it always returning the partially covered despite the windows is fully covered or uncovered.

I am using this in the EnumWindows

```
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    if (hdc) {
        RECT rcClip, rcClient;
    
        switch (GetClipBox(hdc, &rcClip)) {
        case NULLREGION:
            LOGGER->info("completely covered"); break;
        case SIMPLEREGION:
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
            if (EqualRect(&rcClient, &rcClip)) {
                LOGGER->info("completely uncovered");
            }
            else {
                LOGGER->info("partially covered");
            }
            break;
        case COMPLEXREGION:
            LOGGER->info("partially covered");
            break;
        default:
            LOGGER->info("no result");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I personally always avoid logging the same output in different cases.

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me, how do you implement the `LOGGER->info` function. I can record the coverage of all windows by writing a file.

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT For Logging part , I am using spdlog.

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT if you dont mind can you provide the souce file please.

Comment: @dineshlpu I use the same code, just replace `LOGGER->info` with writing to a file. I tried to test `notepad`, when it is completely on the desktop, it outputs `completely uncovered`, and when it is partially outside the desktop Output `partially covered`, output `completely uncovered` when it is minimized or not at all on the desktop

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT okay thankyou. Does it work if the notepad is covered by the other windows??

Comment: @dineshlpu Covering by other windows will not affect the result, because you use `GetClipBox` and `EqualRect` to compare the logical coordinates of the window, and will not be affected by being covered by other windows.

Comment: Is there any way that we could know if the window is visible to the user?

Comment: a duplicate? [How to determine if any part of the window is visible to Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786181/how-to-determine-if-any-part-of-the-window-is-visible-to-screen)

Comment: consider a situation where many applications in restored size and I want to if one of the application windows is being shown..

Comment: This should be a new question, maybe you can post a new question.